# Jquery event.target não funciona no IE8

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Oi. Estou com um problema com o IE8. O código abaixo funciona no chrome e no firefox, mas não no IE. Assim que ele chega nessa primeira linha, o erro do IE diz "objeto esperado".

O que eu tenho é uma img dentro de uma div#prods. Quando clicada, esse código testa [se o que foi clicado é uma img "&&" se o id dela é diferente de "#img-display"(id de outra img dentro da div que não deve acionar a função) "&&" se o id é diferente do valor de eh_tb].

```
$('#prods').on('click', find("img"), function(event) {
    if( $(event.target).is('img') && ($(event.target).attr('id') != 'img-display') &&
($(event.target).attr('id') != eh_tb) ) {

        //PROCESSAMENTO AQUI
    }                                              
});
```

O que está no HTML é um menu. E uma div#prods vazia. Qd clico em um link do menu, ele chama uma função PHP por ajax para exibir o conteúdo de uma pasta dentro de #prods.

O código PHP coloca dentro de #prods:

- uma serie de imgs que sao os thumbnails(essas são as imgs testadas na função qd clicadas);
- um "p";
- uma "img" que é a #img-display;

OBS.: a variável "eh_tb" guarda qual thumbnail está exibindo seu conteúdo no momento. É apenas para não carregar a função e acabar carregando o mesmo conteúdo de novo.

Eu tive que usar event.target porque o conteúdo é gerado dinamicamente pelo PHP. Alguém tem uma solução para esse código rodar no IE8?

Comment: O que é esse `find("img")`? E você pode usar `this`, mas `event.target` devia funcionar, o jQuery normaliza isso.

Comment: Teste este código: http://jsfiddle.net/Sergio_fiddle/a4rLmb8m/ - a razão de usar uma biblioteca como o jQuery é ser compativel em browsers diferentes. A não ser que esteja a usar a versão 2.0 o IE deve funcionar bem. Mas como o bfavaretto referiu, o `find(img)` está errado aí

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/63395/quando-usar-this-e-quando-usar-event-target

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51206/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-do-this-e-do-event-target/51207#51207

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O jQuery (nas versöes 1.x) funciona do mesmo modo no IE8 e outros browsers mais modernos. Essa é  grande vantagem de usar uma biblioteca.

Dito isso, o seu problema está no código.
Remova `find("img")` e coloque somente `"img"` como o @bfavaretto [indicou](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/28945/jquery-event-target-n%C3%A3o-funciona-no-ie8#comment54075_28945). Assim delega o evento e isso só por sí já fará com que possa remover a sua primeira condicäo no seu `if`.

Dentro da funcäo parametro/callback do `.on()` pode usar o `this` em vez de `event.target` e näo precisa de jQuery para ir buscar a ID.

A minha sugestäo de código é:

```
$('#prods').on('click', "img", function(event) {
    if (this.id == 'img-display' || this.id == eh_tb) return false;
    //PROCESSAMENTO AQUI

});
```

Comment: Ficou perfeito, acrescento apenas que nessa situação `eh_tb` esta se referindo ao valor de uma variável e não a um elemento com `id="eh_tb"`, não sei se essa é a intenção real do @Dtag. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaderw/5hsq214s/) com a solução que fiz enquanto você respondia...

Comment: @Jader o Dtag escreveu na pergunta "&& o id é diferente do valor de eh_tb", daí ter feito assim.

Comment: sim, mas `eh_tb` é uma variável, e `"eh_tb"` é uma string.

Comment: @Jader, pois, vamos ter de esperar por clarificacäo.

Comment: Muito obrigado a todos, especialmente @Sergio. Funcionou perfeitamente utilizando $(this).attr('id').
O find('img') veio de uma solução que eu tinha pesquisado. Não lembro agora, mas tinha entendido(obviamente errado) que so "img" não funcionaria. Tão simples, mas estou aprendendo. hahaha. Mais uma vez, obrigado! Abçs

Comment: @Jader eh_tb é realmente a variável. Os thumbs têm id=tb[um numero]. Então, por exemplo, eh_tb = 'tb1', significa que o primeiro thumb está ativo.
Ah, agora entendi sua confusão. Coloquei entre aspas só para destacar do texto. Tenho essa mania, mas vi agora q pode ser confuso. Foi mal.