# Qual a diferença do $(this) e do $(event.target)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Bom, surgiu uma dúvida enquanto eu estava mexendo com jQuery e o código funcionou perfeitamente no Chrome usando o evento `$(event.target)`, já no Firefox só funcionou com `$(this)`, então surgiu essa dúvida. Qual a principal diferença entre eles?

```
$(document).on('click', '.bermuda', function(e){
    $(e.target).fadeOut(300);
});

$(document).on('click', '.bermuda', function(){
    $(this).fadeOut(300);    
});
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

O `$(this)` se trata exatamente do elemento atual, onde se definiu o evento.

Já o `$(event.target)` pode se tratar tanto do elemento onde o evento está atribuído como do filho desse elemento atual, onde se definiu o evento.

Exemplo JQuery:

```
$(document).click(function(e){
    console.log(e.target); // #teste
    console.log(this); // #document
});
```

Exemplo HTML:

```
<body>
   <div id="teste">aqui será clicado</div>
</body>
```

No seu caso, se `.bermuda` tiver algum elemento filho, como um `<p>` ou um `<img/>`, ao clicar sobre eles, o evento de `.bermuda` será acessado, porém `event.target` retornará o elemento clicado, e não `.bermuda`.

É por isso que em alguns caso se usa `event.stopPropagation()`, para pode evitar essa *propagação do evento* dos elementos filhos para os pais.

Comment: Obrigado, resposta bastante esclarecedora...

Answer (score 9):

O `this` se refere ao elemento ao qual foi anexado o evento. Já o `event.target` se refere ao elemento que disparou o evento.

Por exemplo, suponha que você esteja manipulando uma tabela e queira pegar o evento `click` em uma `td`.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="teste">
            <img src="testando.png" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

$("#teste").on("click", function(event) {
    console.log(this);
    console.log(event.target);
});
```

Neste exemplo, se o usuário clicar na **imagem**, o `event.target` se refere a imagem e o `this` se refere a `td#teste`.

Comment: Obrigado, resposta bastante esclarecedora...