# Quando usar this e quando usar event.target

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hoje surgiu uma dúvida, apesar que com os testes que fiz consegui resolver várias delas.

Mas assim, quando devo usar `e.target` e quando devo usar `This` . Pois ontem quando descobri o e.target, passei a usá-lo. Mas a desvantagem, é que este eu preciso de verificar onde estou clicando para fazer o determinado evento. Mas percebi que ele é bem útil quando utilizo o evento em `$(document)`.

Outra desvantagem do `this`, é que devo apontar para o elemento ( digamos que tenho divs com as mesmas classes como filho), tenho que determinar se é a primeira, segunda etc, Eu pelo menos não consegui pegar um filho de `THIS` que foi `clicado`, ou um elemento `PAI`, sem apontar qual era. Tive que dar um `find` para especificar qual eu desejava.

Isso são minhas persepções. Gostaria de saber de vocês, quando devo usar cada uma.

http://jsfiddle.net/W4Km8/4919/

Comment: Relacionada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51206/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-do-this-e-do-event-target/51207#51207

Answer (score 4):

Quando usar um ou outro depende do que se pretende.

Se usares por exemplo:

```
<div>
    <button onclick="clicaMe(event);">Clica-me!</button>
</div>
```

e no JavaScript

```
var el = document.querySelector('div');

function clicaMe(e) {
    console.log('inline this', this); // vai dar window
    console.log('inline e.target', e.target); // vai dar button
}
el.onclick = function (e) {
    console.log('onclick this', this); // vai dar el, ou seja "div"
    console.log('onclick e.target', e.target); // vai dar button
}
el.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    console.log('event handler this', this); // vai dar el, ou seja "div"
    console.log('event handler e.target', e.target); // vai dar button
});
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2fqp1se6/

Repara que quando corres uma função via `onclick` **inline** no HTML o escopo do `this` vai ser `window`. Nos outros casos o `this` é o próprio elemento que recebeu o eventhandler ou onclick. O e.target é sempre o elemento concreto que recebeu o click, descendente do elemento ao qual foi amarrado o event handler caso o click tenha sido disparado nele.

**Há um outro parâmetro a ter em conta:** `bubbling` (ou propagação do evento).

Repara neste exemplo:

```
var el = document.querySelector('div');
var btn = document.querySelector('button');

el.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    console.log('div this', this); // vai dar el, ou seja "div"
    console.log('div e.target', e.target); // vai dar button
});
btn.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    console.log('button this', this); // vai dar button
    console.log('button e.target', e.target); // vai dar button
});
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2fqp1se6/2/

Neste caso ambos os event handlers são disparados pois uma vez que o button recebe o click ele propaga o evento para os elementos pai, e disparando os seus eventhandlers nesse caminho. Repara ainda que o eventhandler de `btn` dispara primeiro!.

Isto pode ser algo útil para distinguir entre `this` e `e.target` quando se quer saber em detalhe qual o elemento clicado.