# Duvidas sobre JavaScript e HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Galera é o seguinte, Estou tentando fazer um ação só que não está saindo como eu espero.

*Código HTML *

```
<div id="apresentar">
    <img src="img2/fechar.png" class="fechar-foto">
    <div id="foto-grande" ><img src="" width="100%" height="100%"><p></p></div>
    </div>
<header>
    <div id="logo"><a href="index.html"><img src="img2/Logo.png" width="220" height="220"  class="logo zoom" alt="Página Inicial"></a></div>
    <div id="sociais">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/BlitzHaus" target="_blank"><img src="img/facebook.png" class="fade" alt="Facebook"></a>
        <a href="https://twitter.com/blitz_haus" target="_blank"><img src="img/twitter.png" class="fade" alt="Twitter"></a>
    </div>
</header>
<!--<nav class="fade-in um">-->
<nav>
    <ul id="menu-principal">
        <span class="ativo-desl"></span>
        <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="programacao.html">PROGRAMAÇÃO</a></li>
        <li><a href="parceiros.html">PARCEIROS</a></li>
        <li><a href="galeria.html" class="ativo" id="selecionado">GALERIA</a></li>
        <li><a href="localizacao.html">LOCALIZAÇÃO</a></li>
        <li><a href="contato.html">CONTATO</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="corpo">
    <section id="breadcrumb" class="fade-in um"><a href="index.html"><span>Home</span></a><span> > </span><span class="ativo">Galeria de Fotos</span></section>
    <div id="conteudo">
        <h1 id="titulo-principal" class="fade-in dois">GALERIA DE FOTOS</h1>
        <img src="img2/galeria/img01.jpg" class="img-galeria fade-in tres" alt="Foto1">
        <img src="img2/galeria/img02.jpg" class="img-galeria fade-in tres" alt="Foto2">
        <img src="img2/galeria/img03.jpg" class="img-galeria fade-in tres" alt="Foto3">
        <img src="img2/galeria/img04.jpg" class="img-galeria fade-in quatro" alt="Foto4">
        <img src="img2/galeria/img05.jpg" class="img-galeria fade-in quatro" alt="Foto5">
        <img src="img2/galeria/img06.jpg" class="img-galeria fade-in quatro" alt="Foto6">
        <img src="img2/galeria/img07.jpg" class="img-galeria fade-in cinco" alt="Foto7">
        <img src="img2/galeria/img08.jpg" class="img-galeria fade-in cinco" alt="Foto8">
        <img src="img2/galeria/img09.jpg" class="img-galeria fade-in cinco" alt="Foto9">
        <img src="img2/galeria/img10.jpg" class="img-galeria fade-in cinco" alt="Foto10">
        <img src="img2/galeria/img11.jpg" class="img-galeria fade-in cinco" alt="Foto11">
        <img src="img2/galeria/img12.jpg" class="img-galeria fade-in cinco" alt="Foto12">
        <img src="img2/galeria/img13.jpg" class="img-galeria fade-in cinco" alt="Foto13">
    </div>
</div>
```

*Código JavaScript*

```
$(function(){
$("#conteudo img").click(function(){
    var image = $(this).attr('src');
    var legenda = $(this).attr('alt');
    $("#apresentar").fadeIn(300);
    $("#foto-grande").fadeIn(300);
    var vlr = $(this).position().top / 2;
    $('#apresentar').css('top',vlr)
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: vlr}, 400);
    $('#foto-grande img').attr('src', image); 
    $('#foto-grande p').text(legenda);
    $('#foto-grande').hover(function(){ $('#foto-grande p').fadeIn(300)} , function (){$('#foto-grande p').fadeOut(300)});
    document.body.style.overflow='hidden';
    $('#apresentar').click(function(){ $('#apresentar').fadeOut(300); document.body.style.overflow='';});
  });
});

function fechar(){
$('#apresentar').fadeOut(300);
document.body.style.overflow='';
}
```

Estou tentado fazer o seguinte, quando a pessoa clica na Div apresentar ele fecha a DIV, e quando a pessoa clica na div foto-grande não faz nada, estilo o facebook. Mas quando clico na div foto-grande, ele fecha por estar dentro da div apresentar.

Por favor me ajudem :'( .

Comment: Podes colocar o HTML todo? faltam elementos como `#conteudo`

Comment: "quando a pessoa clica na div foto-grande não faz nada, estilo o facebook. Mas quando clico na div foto-grande, ele fecha por estar dentro da div apresentar.", não entendi.

Comment: Se entendi corretamente, basta você utilizar o método `stopPropagation` ao clicar na div `#foto-grande` para impedir que o evento seja disparado nos elementos pais. https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

Comment: Oslei, é mais ou menos isso, como eu aplico o stopPropagation?
Sergio o código inteiro já está disponível.,

Comment: Romario: o que o @Oeslei sugeriu é o que precisas (talvez ele junte resposta com isso). Para além disso dá uma olhada aqui para perceberes melhor qual o elemento que deves referir dentro do event handler: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/63399/129

Comment: Vlw pessoal pela a ajuda, obrigado mesmo. :D

Comment: Romario, também podes usar assim: http://jsfiddle.net/q7hnbye0/, esse código faz o que queres?

Comment: @Sergio, Essa classe seria do botão X essa já está configurada. A minha ideia é tipo as fotos do facebook, quando vc clica em uma ela abre bloqueado a barra de rolagem e com uma div que deixa o fundo escuro, quando vc clica nessa parte escura a foto se fecha e tbm nesse X, o problema era que quando eu clicasse na foto, fechava a foto também, mas não era para acontecer nada quando eu clicasse na foto. Entendeu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A idéia é adicionar um handler para o evento `onclick` da div filha, mas retornar `false` neste evento. Isso fará com que o evento pare de ser processado, e deste modo a `div` pai não será escondida.

Fiz um Fiddle para exemplificar:

https://jsfiddle.net/4jucz895/

Nele, está obviamente simplificado, pois não adicionei imagens nem outros elementos dentro da `div`. Mas a idéia é esta, basta expandir para os elementos que você não desja que propague o evento `onclick`.

Para simplificar isso, você poderia inclusive criar uma classe `click-prevent`, por exemplo, e adicionar às `div`'s que não devem permitir propagação do evento `onclick`, criando assim uma solução em JS genérica:

```
<div id="apresentar">
    <div class="click-prevent"></div>
</div>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#apresentar").click(function () {
            $(this).fadeOut(100);
        });
        $(".click-prevent").click(function () { return false; });
    });
</script>
```

**Seleção de `DIV`**

Vou responder a pergunta feita em comentário modificando o exemplo acima.

Imagina que você possua várias `div`'s com `id="apresentar"`, e que o comportamento de todas devem ser iguais, ocultando-as apenas quando o clique é realizado nelas.

Você poderia implementar este comportamento utilizando selectores do CSS, em especial o seletor `>`, que faz referência ao elemento filho imediato.

Imagine o HTML:

```
<div id="apresentar">
    <div id="filha">
        <div id="neta">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="apresentar">
    <div id="filha">
        <div id="neta">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Utilizando  o seletor `#apresentar div`, selecionaríamos todas as `div`'s dentro da `div#apresentar`. Se utilizarmos `#apresentar > div`, selecionamos apenas as `div`'s que são filhas (não "netas", etc) da `div#apresentar`.

Veja este outro Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/carwmhLc/2/

Repare que o CSS vermelho foi aplicado a todas as `div`, sejam elas filhas ou netas. Mas o CSS que aplica a cor branca, foi aplicado apenas a `div` filha da `div#apresentar`. Isto ocorre por causa do seletor `>`.

Repare também, que utilizamos este seletor com o jQuery. Clickando nas `div`'s vermelhas, o `alert` é disparado uma vez por causa do evento `onclick` registrado na vermelha, e outra por causa do evento `onclick` registrado na branca. Adicionalmente, temos uma terceira vez que o evento é disparado por causa do comportamento do jQuery de não substituir callbacks, e sim acumulá-los e disparar todos registraos em um mesmo evento.

Comment: Po cara me salvou *-*, pode me explicar um pouco mais de como selecionar ações só para div pai, ou div filha? :D
Obrigado cara :D

Comment: Vlw cara me ajudou basatante, agora consegui entender melhor como colocar um evento somente na div filho e na div pai.

Comment: @RomarioPires Adicionei detalhes sobre os seletores. Veja se te ajuda!

Comment: Vlw cara, vc me ajudou bastante, nem passava isso pela minha cabeça. Obrigado mesmo.